# Maximum runs of composites in arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Is there a proof that every arithmetic progression of gap $p$ has a prime in the interval $[p, p^2)$?

Put another way, can you prove the following:

For all primes $p$, and all integers $0 \le m <p$, there exists $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $1\le n < p$ such that  $np+m$ is prime.

I think I have a proof sketch but it's fiddly and I don't want to reinvent the wheel (likely badly).

To illustrate, here's the result checked for $p = 5$:

Arithmetic progressions with gaps $5$ from $5$ to $24$ ($p$ to $p^2-1$):

$\boldsymbol{5},10,15,20$
$6,\boldsymbol{11},16,21$
$\boldsymbol{7},12,\boldsymbol{17},22$
$8,\boldsymbol{13},18,\boldsymbol{23}$
$9,14,\boldsymbol{19},24$

As you can see, in **bold**, all of these arithmetic progressions have at least one prime. If one of these sequences didn't have a prime the theorem would be disproven for $p = 5$.

Note that proving that every arithmetic progression of gap $p$ and length $(p-1)$ has at least one number coprime to $(p-1)!$ should also prove the above, and indeed is more general, as if $n$ is coprime to $(p-1)!$ and is less than $p^2$ then it has to be prime.

Comment: What do you mean?  There are progressions of period $p$ with no primes at all in them (or exactly one prime). Then again, there are arbitrarily large blocks of consecutive composite numbers.  But I'm not sure what you mean by "the interval $[p,p^2)$".

Comment: What I mean by the interval $[p, p^2)$ is ${p, p+1, ... , p^2-1}$

Arithmetic progressions have terms in that interval of `pm + n` for `1 <= m < p` and `0 <= n < p`.

Comment: I've added a more formal explanation.

Comment: @Clinton I edited the formatting and wording of the formal statement. If I have misunderstood your intentions, feel free to edit.

Comment: @jgon I think that's right. Thanks!

Comment: polynomial remainder theorem.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee can you perhaps outline in an answer how the polynomial remainder theorem leads to the result I'm attempting to prove?

Comment: It'd wittle down cases. if 3 divides none of the first 3, then 3 doesn't divide any of them because it would have the same remainder by adding 3 to the variable ( adding a multiple of 3 in the process) etc.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Given I'm attempting to prove this forall p (i.e. infinite number of cases) having less cases still seems to be an infinite number of cases unless I'm missing something

Comment: $\forall p\not\equiv 0 \bmod 3, p^2+m\equiv 0 \bmod 3, \forall m\equiv 2 \bmod 3, \implies pk+m\equiv 0 \bmod 3,\forall m\equiv 2 \bmod 3, k\equiv p \bmod 3$ forall primes p not equal to three a full 9th of all values to be tested are now deleted ( counting different m values)

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately hopeless. The best bound as of now is that there exists an absolute constant $c$ such that for all integers $m$ with $0 \le m < p$, there is a prime of the form $np+m$ in the interval $[p, cp^5)$. The Generalized Riemann Hypothesis would imply a prime in the interval $[p, p^2 (\log (p))^2)$. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Some comments too long for the comment area; NOT A FULL ANSWER

The notion of arithmetic progressions in this question can be recast as residue classes. Each progression can be expressed as $np+a$, or numbers $k_i$ such that $k_i\equiv a \mod{p}$. Plainly, $a\in \{0,1,\dots p-1\}$, so there will be exactly $p$ such arithmetic progressions, and if each contains at least on prime, then there must be at least $p$ primes (including $p$ itself) in the interval $[p,p^2)$.

This is a reasonable expectation, but saying that is different from a proving that it will be the case with regard to every $p$. By the Prime Number Theorem, the number of primes less than $p^2$ will be approximately $\frac{p^2}{\ln p^2}=\frac{p^2}{2\ln p}$, and the number of primes less than $p$ will be approximately $\frac{p}{\ln p}$. The number of primes in the interval will be the difference of those two, or $\frac{p^2-2p}{2\ln p}$, which is greater than $p$ for all but the few smallest primes. So in general, there should be a sufficient number of primes in the interval to support the conclusion. Proving that there is at least one prime in each residue class would be the next task.